# c# Linq To XML , получить значения всех полей

Tags: c#, linq2xml

Есть файл Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<Groups>
 <Group ID ="1121321" Master="He1by">
   <Name>New name </Name>
   <User>UserName</User>
   <User>UserName2</User>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

Как получить значения полей User? Если есть следующий запрос:

```
var items=(from xe in fdoc.Element("Groups")?.Elements("Group")
    where xe.Element("Name").Value.Equals(str)
    select xe);
```

Т.е как мне занести  , например в List , значения UserName и UserName2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items=(from xe in fdoc.Element("Groups")?.Elements("Group")
    where xe.Element("Name").Value.Equals(str)
    select (from xel in xe.Elements("User") select xel.Value).ToList());
```

Однако такой запрос вернет `IEnumerable<List<String>>` по причине того, что для каждого элемента типа Group будет возвращен список значений User.

Если же Ваш фильтр по Name должен возвращать одно значение (или ничего при неудаче) добавьте FirstOrDefault()

```
var items=(from xe in fdoc.Element("Groups")?.Elements("Group")
    where xe.Element("Name").Value.Equals(str)
    select (from xel in xe.Elements("User") select xel.Value).ToList()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Результатом такого запроса будет `List<String>`

Для проверки того, что значение Name уникально, можете воспользоваться методом SingleOrDefault, тогда будет выброшено исключение если найдется несколько элементов с искомым Name